# chromium ignores /etc/resolver/example.com

Tags: macos, dns, chromium

I am overriding dns entries on a Mac for example.com by using a file in /etc/resolver/example.com that contains the nameservers to use.

The problem is Chromium seems to ignore these files. I have flushed dns cache, cleared browser cache (which worked in chrome)...but I still cannot get chromium to pickup the proper dns settings for the domain.

Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all use the proper DNS settings for the domain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome (and I assume chromium) has an available built-in resolver.  It will ignore local resolve settings.

go to chrome://flags/#enable-async-dns And make sure it is set to disabled.

Also you can goto chrome://net-internals/#dns and force chrome to flush its internal dns cache.